# REGEXP_SUBSTR Oracle different to regext.com

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle12c

I'm using this regex

`#([^#\s]*)#`

(in C# and [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) working fine)

but with `REGEXP_SUBSTR` in Oracle, I'm getting a different result.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('test #2 #123456789#  #blabla #1','#([^#\s]*)#') from dual
```

Oracle = `#2 #`

C#/regexr.com = `#123456789#`

Did anybody have an idea how to get the same result in Oracle?

Comment: Using plain English, what rules should be followed to get the desired result?

Comment: You need `#([^#[:space:]]*)#`

Comment: `[^#\s]` matches characters that are not `#` or `\ ` or `s` (and not as you are expecting `#` or a whitespace character). If you want to match white spaces in a character set then you need to use the POSIX expression `[:space:]` rather than the PERL `\s` expression.

Comment: Please describe how the result is supposed to be returned? Is it a `#` delimited string and you are trying to return the 3rd field?

Comment: @EJEgyed The OP is asking for the same behaviour as [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/5dhg7); this regular expression is finding a substring between two sequential `#`s that are separated by no whitespace characters. As previously metioned, this could be by adapting the OP's query to use the POSIX character set `[:space:]` or just using the non-greedy regular expression `#\S*?#`.

Comment: this is what I'm looking for #([^#[:space:]]*)#

I was looking for a regex which returns a string surrounded by hashtags but without any whitspaces. 
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use a combination of `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` to get the desired result

#### Query

```
WITH strings (str_val) AS (SELECT 'test #2 #123456789#  #blabla #1' FROM DUAL)
SELECT SUBSTR (str_val,
               instr(str_val, '#', 1,2),
               instr(str_val, '#', 1,3) - instr(str_val, '#', 1,2) + 1)
  FROM strings;
```

Comment: This is not the same as you have hardcoded that you need the value between the second and third `#`.

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that the string seems to be a `#` delimited string and they are trying to get the 3rd field. Definitely need some clarification from the author of the question.